# Java Apache POI (стили текста/свойства ячеек)

Tags: java, apache, swing, excel, шрифты

Есть небольшой код на экспорт данных с Jtable в excel

```
public class ExcelOrders {

    private static String getCellValue(JTable table, int x, int y) {
        return table.getValueAt(x, y).toString();
    }

    public static void writeToExcel (JTable table, String folder) {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.createSheet();
        TreeMap<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<>();
        data.put("-1", new Object[]{table.getColumnName(0), table.getColumnName(1), table.getColumnName(2),
            table.getColumnName(3), table.getColumnName(4), table.getColumnName(6), table.getColumnName(8),
            table.getColumnName(9)});
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            data.put(Integer.toString(i), new Object[] {getCellValue(table, i, 0), getCellValue(table, i, 1),
                getCellValue(table, i, 2), getCellValue(table, i, 3), getCellValue(table, i, 4),
                getCellValue(table, i, 6), getCellValue(table, i, 8), getCellValue(table, i, 9)});
        }     
        Set<String> ids = data.keySet();
        XSSFRow row;
        int rowId = 0;
        for (String key: ids) {
            row = ws.createRow(rowId++);            
            Object[] values = data.get(key);
            int celId=0;
            for (Object o: values) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(celId++);
                cell.setCellValue(o.toString());
                cell.setCellStyle(styleExcel.createHeadingStyle(wb));
            }
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(folder+"\\"+"Список рабочих.xlsx"));
            wb.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception Ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ExcelOrders.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, Ex);
            new errorDialog(null, new StringEntered(Ex.getMessage()).getStringEntered(100),
            new StringEntered().toString(Ex.getStackTrace()), "Программная ошибка", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

Хочу применить свойства жирности и растягивание по содержимому ячейки к первой строке

Написан небольшой метод

```
public static CellStyle createHeadingStyle(XSSFWorkbook book) {
        XSSFCellStyle style = book.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont fontHeader = book.createFont();
        fontHeader.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        style.setFont(fontHeader);
        return style;
    }
```

В данном методе шрифт становится жирным во всех ячейках
Как мне допилить его чтобы свойство bold применялось к 1 строке и также расширялось по содержимому в ячейки

Расширение сделал. Как установить жирный шрифт только 1 строке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет необходимости создавать новый стиль для каждой ячейки - создайте предварительно 2 стиля: для 1й строки и для всех остальных, и затем используйте их. Код для стилей:

```
public static CellStyle createBaseStyle(XSSFWorkbook book) {
    XSSFCellStyle style = book.createCellStyle();
    //необходимые настройки
    return style;
}

public static CellStyle createHeadingStyle(XSSFWorkbook book) {
    XSSFCellStyle style = book.createCellStyle();
    XSSFFont fontHeader = book.createFont();
    fontHeader.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    style.setFont(fontHeader);
    return style;
}
```

И измененный вариант заполнения таблицы:

```
Set<String> ids = data.keySet();
    XSSFRow row;
    CellStyle baseStyle = styleExcel.createBaseStyle(wb);
    CellStyle headingStyle = styleExcel.createHeadingStyle(wb);
    int rowId = 0;
    for (String key : ids) {
        row = ws.createRow(rowId);
        Object[] values = data.get(key);
        int celId = 0;
        for (Object o : values) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(celId++);
            cell.setCellValue(o.toString());
            cell.setCellStyle(rowId == 0 ? headingStyle: baseStyle);
        }
        rowId++;
    }
```

**UPD** для проверки типов значений

```
for (Object o : values) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(celId++);
        if (o instanceof Double) {
            cell.setCellValue((Double)o);
        } else if (o instanceof Integer) {
            cell.setCellValue((Integer)o);
        }
        // else if прочие типы - decimal и т.д.
        else {
            cell.setCellValue(o.toString());
        }
        cell.setCellStyle(rowId == 0 ? headingStyle: baseStyle);
    }
```

Comment: Подскажите еще такое, при экспорте с jtable забирается столбец 8 со значениями с точкой (567.2354)
Вставил формулу на сложение столбца 8
Расчет показывает 0, т.к. с точкой он не сложит.
Как мне заменить именно в 8 столбце точку на запятую во время экспорта ?

Comment: Проблема в том, что при вставке значения вы вставляете его как строку, а нужно как число. И тогда будет в документе будет отображаться точка либо запятая в зависимости от настроек ОС. В методе getCellValue(JTable table, int x, int y) не нужно приводить к String - пусть возвращает Object, а в cell.setCellValue(...) необходимо вставлять значение в зависимости от типа.

Comment: Перевел на integer, ругается мол дай string, т.к. в таблице присутствует string,int,bigdecimal
перевел на object, ошибки ушли но также экспортирует с точкой

Comment: А зачем на integer? Тебе нужен вещественный тип - Double например. Из Jtable ты получаешь Object, затем перед вставкой в Excel-таблицу проверять какого типа значение (o instanceof Double, o instanceof Integer и т.д.), кастуешь к нужному типу и вставляешь

Comment: вы имеете ввиду на данном этапе

                cellData.setCellValue(o.toString());
только там значения и string и decimal и int ...
как мне записать это  ?

Comment: добавил изменения в ответ, но к сожалению сейчас у себя не могу проверить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63255/discussion-between-user-and-nikolay).